# Cucumber testing - getting RoutingError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, bdd

What's wrong, guys. Please help.
When i run my cucumber test, i've got this error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"accounts"} (ActionController::RoutingError)
      ./features/support/paths.rb:40:in `path_to'
```

rake routes shows:

```
account GET    /accounts/:id(.:format)        {:action=>"show", :controller=>"accounts"}
```

cucumber_test.feature

```
   Scenario:
    Given...
    And...
    Then i should be on Show page
```

features/support/paths.rb

```
when /^Show page$/
      account_path @account
```

routes.rb

```
Myapp::Application.routes.draw do  
resources :accounts
```

Comment: What does @account.inspect show?

Comment: Andy, How can i put @account.inspect to my running cucumber test?

Comment: Add "puts @account.inspect" as the first line in the When step.

Comment: Yep, guys. You were right, it returns nil. And now i gonna break my brain, cuz really don't know why it is nil :(

Comment: Well, it's more like: why do you expect it NOT to be nil??

Answer (score 1):

Imho you're assuming wrong that somehow you have @account variable set.

Here are some of the possible approaches. You could use:

```
when /the account page/
account_path(Account.first)
```

or better, more clean and reusable (I don't know your schema for Account so I used generic 'name'):

```
when /the account page for account named ".*"/
        account_name = page_name.scan(/".*"/).first.gsub("\"", '') 
        account = Account.find_by_name(account_name)
        account_path(account)
```

Of course as long as you've defined your "I am on" webstep like this:

```
Given /^(?:|I )am on (.+)$/ do |page_name|
  visit path_to(page_name)
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll use your great approach.