# How to direct to the user update route "put user_path" on cucumber (Rails/cucumber/rspec)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, cucumber

I would like to use cucumber to make the equivalent of a test i have on rspec.

on rspec, I write:

```
                describe "submitting to the update action" do
                before { put user_path(user) }
                specify { response.should redirect_to(new_user_session_path)}
            end
```

On cucumber I have created a scenario but my problem is that it does not understand when I try to tell him to do the **update action** as follows:

```
When /^I submit to the update action$/ do
put user_path   
end
```

I've tried also put user_path(user) but it does not work and gives me the error:

```
When I submit to the update action                            # features/step_definitions/user_steps.rb:148
  No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"} (ActionController::RoutingError)
```

I feel like the proper syntax put user_path on rspec does not work on cucumber's features: what should I do? how should I write this on cucumber?

Answer (score 0):

Our routes will probably contain line like this:

```
PATCH/PUT   /user/:id   update  update a specific user
```

And didn't specify the id of object you want to update.

```
When /^I submit to the update action$/ do
  put user_path(user)
end
```

See more details in [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7463191/cucumber-testing-getting-routingerror)